# How can I correctly use z-index to prevent the dropdown menues from buggy overlapping?

Tags: css, select, z-index, dropdown

I found a nicely design dropdown menue (https://codepen.io/sammurphey/pen/BQvZbq) which I would like to use on my website. Unfortunately the dropdowns produce some buggy overlapping when being placed beneath each other.

Here's a pen to depict the problem: https://codepen.io/PLY51/pen/jXQKxR

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
html, body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #666;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  cursor: inherit;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-property: none;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
label.field {
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  margin: 16px;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: opacity;
  z-index: 1;
}
label.field span {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  left: 9px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  transition-property: color, font-size, top;
  z-index: 1;
}
label.field span.required::after {
  color: inherit;
  content: "*";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: -20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
}
.error label.field span {
  color: #f02318;
}
label.field .psuedo_select {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: relative;
  border-color: #666;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
  color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 24px 32px 0 0;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding-top: 24px;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
label.field .psuedo_select::after {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='#666' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <path d='M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z'/> <path d='M0-.75h24v24H0z' fill='none'/> </svg>"), no-repeat;
  content: "";
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition-property: background;
}
label.field .psuedo_select .selected {
  height: 24px;
  left: 1px;
  line-height: 24px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(24px);
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
  will-change: transform;
}
label.field .psuedo_select ul {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition-property: height, opacity;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
label.field .psuedo_select ul li {
  height: 32px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
}
label.field .deselect {
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
}
label.field.focused {
  color: #007bed;
}
label.field.focused .psuedo_select {
  border-color: #007bed;
}
label.field.focused .psuedo_select::after {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='#007BED' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <path d='M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z'/> <path d='M0-.75h24v24H0z' fill='none'/> </svg>"), no-repeat;
}
label.field.focused .psuedo_select ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

As you can see, the dropdown menue works fine when being placed solely (which is aequivalent to the bottom dropdown) but if you put another dropdown beneath the first one, the options of the first one will overlap the second dropdown in a buggy way.

I know that z-index only works if elements have the position property and that the stacking context needs to be considered but unfortunately I am not that familar with CSS and would be glad if someone could give me a hint how to solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's because of the **stacking context**: the child of a sibling element cannot be on top of the other element. No matter how high you set the z-index of the dropdown, it will not be stacked higher than the next dropdown. If you want them to obscure each other, you will have to set the parent elements position to relative and update their z-index when they are active.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to solve the problem using the following function that is updating the z-index onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function:

```
$('.psuedo_select').click(function()    {

$(".field").css("z-index", "1");
$(this).closest(".field").css("z-index", "2");

});
```